# Output SQL Server table to XML in a directory on the server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, export

I'm trying to export my

```
select column1, column2 
from table1
```

into a XML file and save it into a directory of `c:\Test\` on the server.

I would also like the file to be overwritten when the i run the query again with same output xml name.

Is there away of doing this without going through creating a how SSIS Job. I have used the feature `FOR XML AUTO` and `FOR XML PATH` but these do not give you a formed XML that will open as well as the option to save into a location.

Any ideas on how to do this would be good!

I have run the following after Aruns Comment :

I have run the following :

```
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50) DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000) DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000) 
SET @fileName = 'C:\test.xml'  SET @sqlStr = 'select TOP 50 [Key_Scores],    [Total_Scores] from Futures.[dbo].[Aco_Scores] FOR XML PATH (''Key_Scores''),    ROOT (''Key_Scores.Total_Scores'')'
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T' EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

Table is called Aco_Scores and the 2 columns are called Key_Scores and Total_Scores.

Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Futures.dbo.Aco_Scores'.

Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to resolve column level collations

I've entered my columns wrong?

My New Query i have tried is :

This query produces an non opening XML file, Actually i have tried the PATH and AUTO but no joy. -- URL Summary Rotary

```
  DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50) DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000) DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000) 
  SET @fileName = 'C:\XML\Summary_Rotary.XML'  SET @sqlStr = 'select TOP 8 [Top_8_Hits], [Best_Score], [Lowest_Score], [Average_Score], [Final_Rating] from Futures.[dbo].[Summary_Rotary] FOR XML AUTO' 
 SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'  EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

Which produces a non working XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

First in your code you can add `FOR XML AUTO` that will display results in XML.

Then, you can use SSMS to export results to file.

`Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> Sql Server -> General -> Default destination...` for results to file  or `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F`

Lots of T-SQL code based examples [here](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/10/20/save-xml-in-a-file-read-xml-from-a-file/).

Comment: Thanks for that, but is there away for example using the FOR XML AUTO I can pump this directly into a File like using QUERYOUT (Which doesn't seem to work) all in the same query?

Comment: @TheMavs Yeah, take a look at the first example on the link I sent you.  it does just that. There are several others. Pasted below:  `DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)
 
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)
 
SET @fileName = 'E:\SQL_Queries\test.xml'
SET @sqlStr = 'select TOP 50 [ContactID], [Title], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [Suffix], [EmailAddress], [Phone] from AdventureWorks.Person.Contact FOR XML PATH(''Contact''), ROOT(''Person.Contact'')'
 
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'
 
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd`

Comment: Hi Arun, Yes thanks for that, Can you though - What is AdventureWorks.Person.Contact , OK Adventureworks being the database and the person being the table? Or contact? My database is called Aston and table called POS21. What else confused me was the OR XML PATH(''Contact''), ROOT(''Person.Contact'') what should my values be in the contact and person.contact? Thanks Arun

Comment: @TheMavs AdventureWorks is the database name, Person is the schema, and contact is the table. It's database.schema.table. If you are using your database {`USE POS21`;}, you can just call on the table.

Comment: Thanks Arun, this makes sense. I've now got it to produce a file. But when i open the file it does not give any xml format at all, just the first word. This there anything more i need to do to the query to make it open as an XML?

Comment: @TheMavs can you share your query? did you use something like XML PATH or XML AUTO

Comment: I have put the query above in the orginal question. Actually i have tried both Auto and path, but no joy

Comment: @TheMavs I tried your script, with a different select statement and it worked for me.  If you run your select query by itself, what happens? `select TOP 8 [Top_8_Hits], [Best_Score], [Lowest_Score], [Average_Score], [Final_Rating] from Futures.[dbo].[Summary_Rotary] FOR XML AUTO`

Comment: Ah - It worked for you? So when i run it produces the XML in the correct location, but when i open the XML in a parser such as Web Browser, its mailformed, and just shows one word, which is the first text in the first column.

Comment: It may be because the XML is missing the declaration - <?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>  ?